# oracle datetime not comparing properly

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am doing comparison between 2dates
01/01/2016 21:01:00 and 31/12/2015 00:12:00
with this code the result should be 1 but it shows 0

```
select 
case when ('01/01/2016 21:01:00'  >= (to_char(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR')-1  ,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MM:SS') )
)
then 1 else 0 end as Result
FROM dual
```

Can someone tell me where did i do wrong?

Comment: You compare strings, not dates.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings not dates:

```
select case
       when TO_DATE( '2016-01-01 21:01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI_SS' )
            >= trunc(sysdate,'YEAR')-1
       then 1
       else 0
       end as Result
FROM   dual
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just comparing the years?

```
select (case when substr('01/01/2016 21:01:00', 7, 4) >= to_char(sysdate - interval '1' year, 'YYYY')
             then 1 else 0
        end) as Result
FROM dual;
```

Your logic is a hodge-podge of date and character logic.

Answer (score 0):

select case
when  to_char(TO_DATE( '2016-01-01 21:01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI_SS' ),'yy')+0 >= to_char(sysdate,'yy')-1
then 1
       else 0
       end as Result
FROM   dual;